# Need to edit the Events web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sharepoint-calendar, events

I'm using the Events Web part on SharePoint online and it fulfills most of the client's needs, however they've come back with some tweaks, for example they want to create events outside of the 30 minute chunks, so for example 9:15 and change some of the field names, for example 'Event participant' to Key contact'.

There doesn't seem an obvious way to make changes to the web part.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no SharePoint out of the box option available to edit the SharePoint default Events web part or "All events" page (`<siteUrl>/_layouts/15/Events.aspx`) or "Add new event" page (`<siteUrl>/_layouts/15/Event.aspx`) to make textual changes.

You have to use the SPFx web part for your requirements if you want customized events web part.

You can find few web part samples here for reference: [SPFx web part samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples)

---

However, You can change the start date and end date from list where your events are stored.

If you are using default "Events" list, you can find it at URL like:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Events/AllItems.aspx
```

[image]

Comment: You might be able to do it using DOM manipulation and SPFx application customizer. But, such DOM manipulations are not supported by Microsoft and your customizations may break in future if Microsoft changes HTML element classes/IDs based on which you will perform DOM manipulation.